# Geometry Shader won't compile in DirectX10 HLSL

Tags: hlsl, directx-10, geometry-shader

I've been trying to code a geometry shader in order to generate billboard systems as explained in Frank Luna's book Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX. I insert the shader into my technique as follows:

```
pass P3
    {
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, VS()));
        SetGeometryShader(CompileShader(gs_4_0, GS()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader( ps_4_0, PS_NoSpecular()));
        SetBlendState(SrcAlphaBlendingAdd, float4( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ), 0xFFFFFFFF );
    }
```

However, this gives the error 1>D3DEffectCompiler : error : No valid VertexShader-GeometryShader combination could be found in Technique render, Pass P3.

The structs for both VS and GS are given below:

```
struct GS_INPUT
{
    float4 PosH : SV_POSITION;   
    float4 PosW : POSITION;   
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD; 
    float3 N : NORMAL;  
    float3 Tangent : TANGENT;
    float3 Binormal : BINORMAL;
};

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;   
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD; 
    float3 N : NORMAL;  
    float3 Tangent : TANGENT;
    float3 Binormal : BINORMAL;
};
```

Should they be the same?

Comment: I also have this warning:
 Semantic TEXCOORD has been placed in different registers in the two stages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the struct used to input and output from the vertex shader, geometry shader and pixel shader. If the vertex shader outputs a PS_INPUT type, then the geometry shader needs to use that PS_INPUT as its input type.